# How to place values in a multidim array - like 6 queens on a chessboard - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this

```
    board = [
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0]
             ];
```

Is there any way, just by using 2 for loops, like this

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            //actions here
        }
    }
```

to place 6 values of 1, first value of 1 to replace the first 0 in the array and the next 5 to be placed using the same rules for placing a queen on a chessboard. The result should look like this

```
    board = [
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0]
             ];
```

I'm new to javascript and I have no clue on how to start this. Could someone please give me some hints.

Comment: Are you asking about the Javascript syntax to set a value in an array, or the queen algorithm itself?

Comment: "same rules for placing a queen on a chessboard" To place or to move? To place doesn't make much sense to me... and if it's to move, well from where? Anyway to create your pattern you can just do `[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6].forEach(function (item, index) { board[index][item] = 1;});`

Comment: "same rules for placing a queen on a chessboard", i mean that I will place on the first value from the array 1 then on the same row and on the same column and on the diagonal there can't be another value of "1", that's why I need to place 6 values in the array, because is the maximum number if I place them like queens on a chessboard

Comment: So you need the algorithm.

Comment: @Shomz - please read the whole message, "Could someone please give me some hints.", I need clues and ideas, not personal opinions, if you are not willing to help or give constructive support find another hobby.

Comment: @SilviuBrucan Ideas **are** personal opinions, just so you know. You won't get far on SO with that attitude since start. I just tried to clarify what you're asking, not being rude like yourself. Anyway, I'll give you a hint in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

board[xCord][yCord] = ValueToInsert;

I may have misread your question, so here is some more info.

You can "push" another array into a 1d array.

```
myArr.push([]);
```

Then you push the value like this:

```
myArr[Xcord].push(YValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a function to check whether placing a queen on xy coordinates is valid. The function would check whether there is a queen in that row, column or diagonals. You can also make those three sub-functions of the main function.

Then, as you go through the loop, use that function for each field and if it returns true, place the queen. If false, move on.

Of course, there will be many solutions in the end, so you might want to keep/store all of them in an array.

Also, think of ways to optimize the algorithm: for example, if you set a queen in a row, there's no need to check any other fields in that row, etc.

And when you decide to really go advanced with your skills, try using recursive functions to generate the solutions.